# PHP: Identical String not being matched together, something to do with (

Tags: php, string, match, bbcode

I am stuck working on a function that translates HTML to bbcode.
I have written my own [spoiler] bbcode tag which translates properly into the HTML equivalent.

But when I try to turn it back into bbcode it doesn't seem to match seemingly identical strings...

After slowly rebuilding it piece by piece to see where the problem is, it turns out that it only fails when I add `onclick="showSpoiler(this)"`

to

```
#<div><input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler(this)"/><div>(.*)</div></div>#ig'
```

I narrowed it further down to the ( brackets. I have tried to escape them like this \(

the html code that is generated from the [spoiler] tag is:

`$1

and the string that it is matched against is this

```
'#<div><input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler(this)"/><div>(.*)</div></div>#ig'
```

here are the conversion functions

```
<?php
//This function let convert BBcode to HTML
function bbcode_to_html($text)
{
    $text = nl2br(htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $in = array(
            '#\[b\](.*)\[/b\]#Usi',
            '#\[i\](.*)\[/i\]#Usi',
            '#\[u\](.*)\[/u\]#Usi',
            '#\[s\](.*)\[/s\]#Usi',
            '#\[img\](.*)\[/img\]#Usi',
            '#\[url\]((ht|f)tps?\:\/\/(.*))\[/url\]#Usi',
            '#\[url=((ht|f)tps?\:\/\/(.*))\](.*)\[/url\]#Usi',
            '#\[left\](.*)\[/left\]#Usi',
            '#\[center\](.*)\[/center\]#Usi',
            '#\[right\](.*)\[/right\]#Usi',
            '#\[spoiler\](.*)\[/spoiler\]#Usi',
            '#\[fuck\](.*)\[/fuck\]#Usi'
        );
    $out = array(
            '<strong>$1</strong>',
            '<em>$1</em>',
            '<span style="text-decoration:underline;">$1</span>',
            '<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">$1</span>',
            '<img src="$1" alt="Image" />',
            '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
            '<a href="$1">$4</a>',
            '<div style="text-align:left;">$1</div>',
            '<div style="text-align:center;">$1</div>',
            '<div style="text-align:right;">$1</div>',
            '<div><input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler(this)" value="Show/Hide" /><div class="inner" style="display:none;">$1</div></div>',
            '<div><input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler(this)"/><div>$1</div></div>'
        );
    $count = count($in)-1;
    for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
    {
        $text = preg_replace($in[$i],$out[$i],$text);
    }
    return $text;
}
//This function let convert HTML to BBcode
function html_to_bbcode($text)
{
    $text = str_replace('<br />','',$text);
    $in = array(
        '#<strong>(.*)</strong>#Usi',
        '#<em>(.*)</em>#Usi',
        '#<span style="text-decoration:underline;">(.*)</span>#Usi',
        '#<span style="text-decoration:line-through;">(.*)</span>#Usi',
        '#<img src="(.*)" alt="Image" />#Usi',
        '#<a href="(.*)">(.*)</a>#Usi',
        '#<div style="text-align:left;">(.*)</div>#Usi',
        '#<div style="text-align:center;">(.*)</div>#Usi',
        '#<div style="text-align:right;">(.*)</div>#Usi',
        '#<div><input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler(this)" value="Show/Hide" /><div class="inner" style="display:none;">(.*)</div></div>#Ui',
        '#<div><input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler(this)"/><div>(.*)</div></div>#ig'
    );
    $out = array(
        '[b]$1[/b]',
        '[i]$1[/i]',
        '[u]$1[/u]',
        '[s]$1[/s]',
        '[img]$1[/img]',
        '[url=$1]$2[/url]',
        '[left]$1[/left]',
        '[center]$1[/center]',
        '[right]$1[/right]',
        '[spoiler]$1[/spoiler]',
        '[fuck]$1[/fuck]'
    );
    $count = count($in)-1;
    for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
    {
        $text = preg_replace($in[$i],$out[$i],$text);
    }
    return $text;
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm going to make an assumption that the reference to 'this' isn't set, so your function isn't running.

Comment: The function works. The [spoiler] tag is functional. it's when I click "edit post" and the html should be turned back to bbcode, that the conversion fails. [bold] and [italics] and all the others work fine, just not [spoiler] and I think this is because there is a bracket

Comment: -1 because in the current form, this question is asking us to play a game of "guess what my codez are".

Comment: I think I have included the relevant bits of code. I will add some more

Comment: You do not need to escape the `]` in your regex - the only time a closing square bracket needs to be escaped is when you want to use one literally in a character class. Also, the `U` modifier should be avoided IMHO, because it is not Perl compatible and other developers may find it confusing. Try `'#\[spoiler](.*?)\[/spoiler]#si'` instead. Although really, rather than trying to roll your own, why not use a [tried and tested BBCode parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=bbcode+php+parser)?

Comment: `(ht|f)tps` will not match against `ftp` if that is your intention.

Comment: If one of your goals of using bbcode is to restrict user input for reasons of safety, against for example xss attacks, then this code isn't suitable. *Properly* implementing a bbcode parser is difficult, despite what all the amateur php tutorials plastered over the intertubez will tell you. Use an existing, mature, well tested bbcode system as suggested by DaveRandom. To be clear, your code is extremely vulnerable to xss attacks right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex you need to escape the braces like so:

```
showSpoiler\(this\)
```

Take care with regular expressions, they are a language on it's own and hard to debug unless you add more functions that do the debugging (e.g. what was matched, output that etc.).

BTW you can run multiple search and replace operations by directly passing the arrays into the function. You don't need to iterate over them.

So better read the manual page about `preg_replace` again and look forward how you can more easily debug your patterns. E.g. test them before putting them into the function and similar.